# How to read google play stacktrace when app crashing on startup

Tags: android, flutter

I am quite new to flutter and app development and i find it really hard to make any sense of the stack traces given by the google play console. Any pointers how to get from this stacktrace to the source of the problem would be great!

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.ddrost.horse_predictions <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000006f06c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+160)
  #01  pc 000000000001e924  /data/app/com.ddrost.horse_predictions-OjQrqd1FMqpadrlYrlrA3g==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
```

When running the app in an emulator before release everything seems to work, also when running on an actual device from android studio. Then when startup up on a device after a release trough google play the app crashes on startup.

This seems to be the case on atleast 4 different types of devices (friends i asked to test if it worked for them). 
Since it works again when i connect my phone to the computer to debug the problem i find it hard to get any clue to the cause of these errors

Comment: You must add a crash reporting library. I'm not sure if you can do it like that.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, do you have any suggestions for a library?

Comment: @Dennis You could take a look at Firebase or Sentry to send you error logs

Comment: @Dennis I personally use Firebase crashlytics. But there are other platforms too as Rutger mentions.

Comment: i will try out sentry. I have build my own java based API as backend so firebase seems less convienent. Thanks for the tip and i hope with it i will find the cause